# How to call Datatable csv button from custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Need to call csv button from my custom button.

```
<button value="Export report to Excel" class="button-default datatable-csv" type="button" id="ExportReporttoExcel">
                <span>Export report to Excel</span>
            </button>
```

Instead of calling it from the Datatable button, i want the same functionality from the above button.

Looking for some configuration changes in Datatable so that i can call my custom button to export the table records as csv.

```
var table=$('#tableId').DataTable( {
    "paging":   true,
    "info":     true,
    "searching": true,      
    ,buttons: true
});


$("#SEARCH").on("keyup search input paste cut", function() {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
});

var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
     buttons: [
       'csvHtml5'
    ]
}).container().appendTo($('#ExportReporttoExcel'));
```

Getting output like below but i need only one button.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just add `onclick="yourFunction()"` attribute?

Comment: when you say "call the button" you mean pragmatically click it right?

Comment: Yes Neville Nazerane, need to export the table to csv file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At last i found the solution.

In Datatable configuration , i added click event for the button to be triggered.

```
buttons: [
        { 
            extend: 'csv',
        }
    ]

$("#ExportReporttoExcel").on("click", function() {
    table.button( '.buttons-csv' ).trigger();
});
```

This works fine for me thanks for the comments and answers

Comment: Its not working for me.Its giving me error that table.button is not a function();

Comment: My code is:    $("#btnExport").on("click", function() {
 var table = $('#tableList').DataTable();
 table.button( '.buttons-excel' ).trigger();
});

Comment: Works like a charm! You saved my day. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

dataTables export buttons is by default enriched with signature classes like `.buttons-excel`, `.buttons-pdf`,  `.buttons-csv` and so on. Take advantage of that :

```
$('#ExportReporttoExcel').on('click', function() {
  $('.buttons-excel').click()
});
```

Comment: I no need of the Datatable buttons at all, in other words i need to customizes the button by changing the location and style

Answer (score 2):

Say you have your own button

`<a href="javascript:;" style="some button style" class="button_export_excel">Export Excel</a>`

And you have your table that you are using the below code for;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        searching: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Then all you need to do is to use this code below:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excel'
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv'
            },
        ]
    });
$('.button_export_excel').click(() => {
    $('#example').DataTable().buttons(0,0).trigger()
})
```

The 0,0 points to excel and if you want to point to csv you do 0,1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to trigger the click event of another button and you are using jQuery (according to your tags), you can use

```
<button onclick="$('#ExportReporttoExcel').click()">Click me</button>
```

This selects the element with the id "ExportReporttoExcel" and triggers a click with using jQuery.

Comment: yeah this answer shows how to trigger the click of the id ExportReporttoExcel. I wasn't sure what your question was but based on your answer it seems you needed to alter the click event of the #ExportReporttoExcel. you can still use the above code if you want the button to do the same on click.

Answer (score 0):

I just got to try this and the `extend: 'csv'` still showed the built-in CSV button for me, also the triggering calls mentioned above didn't work for me either, but the below did.

This is what worked for me.

```
buttons: ['csv'],
```

Then hide the built-in CSV button after creating the Datatable, as follows:

```
$(".buttons-csv").hide();
```

Then trigger its click event from your special button handler.

```
$("#myExportBtn").on('click', function (ev) {
      $(".buttons-csv").trigger("click");
```